# Connecting Synapse Workspace to existing Dedicated SQL Pool

Tags: azure-synapse

We have a development environment Synapse Workspace connected to a development environment Dedicated SQL Pool. We want another development environment Synapse Workspace but we want to connect it to the existing development environment dedicated SQL Pool. So basically, both Synapse workspaces should connect to the same dedicated SQL Pool.

Apparently, I was told this is not possible. Is there any way or a workaround? We want users to be able to query the data using the Synapse workspace in the dedicated SQL pool.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible. What you can do is to create another pool in existing workspace to have two development environments. If this is about letting users querying the data your best bet would be copying the data from one pool to another by Built-in copy task in Synapse:

[Built-in copy task in Synapse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50F4c.png)

You can also specify scheduled copy as well.